# Multiple instances of a class

Tags: python, multiple-instances, instances

I have a class called `Points` and I need to create 100 points.
I need to do something like:

```
class Point(object)
...

for i in range(1,100):
    pi = Point()
```

the points should be named `p1`, `p2`, ... `p100`

The lines above do not work, obviously.

The question is: I know that I could use `exec` inside a loop to create the 100 points but is there any better way to do it without using `exec`?

Comment: See [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Answer (score 8):

You can create several objects using list comprehension:

```
# 100 points in list
points = [Point() for _ in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating/using dynamic variables is considered a bad practice in Python.  It is very easy for you to lose track of them, cause name collisions, etc.

Instead, you can use a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create a dictionary of named instances:

```
points_dict = {"p{}".format(x):Point() for x in range(1, 101)}
```

Then, you can access those instances by name like so:

```
points_dict["p1"]
points_dict["p10"]
# etc.
```

Comment: Fixed.  I actually changed my answer to use a dictionary comprehension so that the instances are named like the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I learned a lot from them.

Anyway, I don't need a list of points or a dictionary of points.

Imagine I start writing:

p1 = Point()
p2 = Point ()
.
.
.
p100 = Point()

I will obtain 100 points and nothing more. That is what I need. I believe it is not a good practice to put in the program 100 lines of code as above! Additionally, the number of points to create will possibly be variable. That is why I thought there should be an elegant way to do it. Thank you.